# How to add noindex meta tag only in beta domain in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, seo

I'm working on a laravel blade project and my site linked with 2 domains and I want to add noindex meta tag only on beta domain.

`www.example.com` don't add meta noindex tag

`www.beta.example.com` add meta noindex tag

Or I just need to add noindex meta tag and this will work automatically on beta domain and not work in actuall domain.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!--Here's the Meta noindex tag-->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    <script type='application/ld+json'>
    {
        "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "@id": "#website",
        "url": "{{ route('home') }}",
        "name": "{{ config('app.name', 'Know Before You Go') }}",
        "alternateName": "Know Before You Go"
    }

    </script>

    @if(isset($seo))
        {{ $seo }}
    @else
        <title>{{ __("seo.homepage.title") }}</title>
    @endif

    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />

<!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')

    @livewireStyles

</head>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your blade template.

Comment: @bassxzero I edit the question you can check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is actually to use Request::getHost();

```
@if (str_contains(Request::getHost(),'beta'))
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
@endif
```

Comment: This is going to be in a blade template so you need to use the correct if syntax.

Comment: check again @bassxzero

Comment: I'm new in laravel and there is `{` and I don't think I need to add this bracket

Comment: @WaleedTariq You're correct.